# arangodb cluster authentication problems

Tags: authentication, cluster-computing, arangodb

I used the DCOS 1.8.8，and applied arangodb 3.1.3 on it. When I set the jwt-key and make the authentication works. I meet the following problems.

1.when I open the web site: http://master.mesos/service/arangodb3, I need to fill the user and pasword, however the password for the "root" is not null. I wonder what's the user and password, and how can i get a available one?

2.when I used the coordinator address instand of the master.mesos, and I enter the web UI, then changed the root's password. what's the amazing thing is that the password I set is not work with the web site(used the master.mesos as Web UI).Also the CLUSTER panel doesn't show well（No data~ in total).

Answer (score 0):

Both ArangoDB and DC/OS are using the standard HTTP Authentication header. Under the hood ArangoDB Authentication is working fine however the reverse proxy that DC/OS is using will not forward any authentication down to arangodb. That is why you can't log in into ArangoDB through the DC/OS whereas it will work from inside the mesos cluster.

This is the reason why you have to manually enable authentication via the extra args and there is no simple checkbox for this :( It is simply not supported right now and not really useable.